# How to specify JRE path for dbeaver on MacOS

Tags: java, dbeaver

I'm trying to setup dbeaver with prestosql driver on MacOS, and it shows me the following error

```
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

[image]

I think it's because dbeaver is using a default JRE without proper setup of credentials, so how I could point it to a different JRE path?

my dbeaver version: Version 6.3.0.201912011827

Comment: What does it say if you click on `Details >>` button in the error window?

Comment: @telcoM I updated the figure

Answer (score 0):

I think it's trying to say: "I'm attempting to use SSL/TLS, but the database I'm querying is presenting a certificate that is not signed by any CA known by the JRE and so cannot be validated." In other words, it would need the certificate of the CA that signed your database's certificate.

Have you checked the settings in database connection settings -> General -> Network settings -> SSL? That apparently allows you to specify the CA certificate to use to validate the database's certificate. See also [this question on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39514212/9197000)

Or if you're using an older version of dbeaver, [see this GitHub issue discussion.](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1954)

[Here's a list of parameters supported by the PrestoSQL JDBC driver.](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html) Note that you can add parameters to the database URL if there is no other way to specify them. In this case you would need to specify `SSLTrustStorePath` to point to a Java keystore containing the necessary CA certificate(s), and possibly also `SSLTrustStorePassword`.

Comment: I've seen that for mysql or postgres driver, but doesn't seem applicable for presto driver currently